# Make blogger pages have their own subdomain

Tags: blogger

Blogger a while back introduced Pages which allows for single web pages outside of the main blog. Which is great for *'About Me'* pages and the like.

My blog is hosted on its own domain, and I want to know how I can map certain subdomains to specific pages.

For example instead of

`http://www.example.com/p/contact.html`

I want it to go to

`http://contact.example.com`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if that can be done from blogger.. but you can do something like this:

I have a sub-domain in my website http://html.comcal.org which redirect to a [Google Calendar](http://www.google.com/calendar/b/0/embed?src=a4lgh95ric33n590179795q0k4@group.calendar.google.com&ctz=Africa/Cairo). That can be done from your domain panel..

Comment: thanks, now lets see if i can dip up my domain registration details!

Answer (score 1):

In your domain registrar, you can add as many sub-domains as you want.

But in Blogger, each Blog   (ie combination of Posts and Pages) can only be pointed to one URL   (ie to either example.com OR   contact.example.com)

What you could do it set up a 2nd blog, which has exactly the same design as the first one, and set its "home page" to the contents-page content.   (Don't give it any other posts.)   Then redirect this 2nd blog to   contact.example.com.

Two disadvantages:

- You now have two blogs to keep "in synch" if you ever do design
  changes in future.
- The home-page redirect option doesn't work for mobile viewes if you
  have a mobile template enabled.   (so it may or may not be an issue
  for you)

So if you're doing this just for the "SEO benefits", I'm not sure that it would be worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, your question just solved my idea, I noew re-structure for my blog, move niche's posts to niche's subdomain (eg: posts about Woodworking will move to https://moc.chebinhdan.com). Now its very clear for me and you:

**1**. Create a new blogspot (https://mocbinhdan.blogspot.com)

**2**. Add 3rd party subdomain to it: https://moc.chebinhdan.com (updating)

**3**. Clone the template from main **blog** to **sub-blog**. Fix the menus items

**4**. Create a new page on new blog: https://moc.chebinhdan.com/p/moc-binh-dan.html (*landing page*)

**5**. **Remove** sidebar and heading of the landing page if has them

**6**. In new blog: **Setting** > **Search preferences** > **Custom ReDirect** > set redirect from **subdomain** (moc.chebinhdan.com) to **landing page**

**7**. In the old blog (https://www.chebinhdan.com) add  the new Menu title > point to landing page URL (or subdomain, now they are the same).

**8**. Lastly: Create a label named "blog". All the posts will has this label. Edit the Menu and add "Blog" on.

Thats it. You could do the same with contact page.
You could check my blog, I've just test with it.
For sample: [Mộc Bình Dân](https://moc.chebinhdan.com/) => redirect to [Tự làm mộc bình dân](https://moc.chebinhdan.com/p/moc-binh-dan.html) (landing page)

Answer (score -1):

Sure you can do so now with your Blogger account if you already have a custom domain name for your Blogspot account. You can add as many subdomains as you want.

Comment: Perhaps you can enlighten us by showing/telling how to do that?